# Specify "super" of nth parameter in Coffeescript class's function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Regarding this `Message` class,

```
class Message
  constructor: (@type) ->

  log: (@title, @text, @delay, @class) ->
    $.growl
      title: @title
      text: '<br>' + @text
      type: @type
      delay: (@delay || 1500)
      class: @class

class Success extends Message
class Error extends Message
class Info extends Message
  log: ->
    super 10000
class Warning extends Message

s = new Success 'success'
e = new Error 'danger'
i = new Info 'info'
w = new Warning 'warning'
```

With four different kinds of `Message`s, I want to make the extended `Info` always pass in a `@delay` of 10000. If this were the first param of `log`, I could just say

```
log: ->
  super 10000
```

But in this case, it's the third param, how do I override just that so that if I say

```
i.log('hello')
```

It will create a `growl` that says "hello" but with a delay of 10 seconds?

Of course, I could just move `@delay` to be the first parameter, but I plan to make more overrides similar to this one for other parameters. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `log` override as a [variadic function](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) to get easier access to the argument list as an array and then simply change the argument array's second last value as needed and splat it back to `super`:

```
class Info extends Message
  log: (args...) ->
    args[args.length - 2] = 10000
    super args...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eHR4n/

Comment: Manipulating `args...` and `arguments` as lists is nice and general, but intent is often obscure.  This log could also be written as: `log: (title, text, delay=10000, klass) -> super(title, text, delay,klass)`.

Comment: @hpaulj: I think throwing a default in the middle of argument list is confusing, it also doesn't force the `delay` to always be 10000. There are lots of ways to do this, I saw this is a quick hack to get around an API that you're not allowed to change; if I could change everything I'd probably end up with named arguments to `log` and defaults in each subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want, though I've made some guesses.  I've also modified it so it runs in the Coffeescript 'try it' browser window.  And removed some extra stuff.

```
growl = (arg)->  # sub for $.growl
  alert ["#{k}:#{v}" for k,v of arg].join(', ')
class Message
  constructor: (@type='msg') ->
  def_delay: 1500
  log: (title, text, delay=0) ->
    growl
      title: title
      text: '<br>' + text
      type: @type
      delay: (delay ||@def_delay)

class Success extends Message
  constructor: (@type='success') ->
class Info extends Message
  constructor: (@type='info') ->
  def_delay : 10000

new Success().log('title','txt')
new Info().log('title','txt')
```

I don't know why you used `@title` etc in the `log` args, unless you wanted to save those values for later use.  That `@arg` form is handy in the constructor arguments, but not commonly used in other functions.

I handle your default delay with an instance variable, `def_delay`.  That could also have been set via the `constructor` as `@delay`.  I think you were barking up the wrong tree with the `super 10000`.  I assume your `info` `log` still needs arguments like `title`.

I also gave `@type` a default value, that varies with class.

Comment: `["#{k}:#{v}" for k,v of arg].join(', ')` doesn't do what you think it does, you're being tricked by your choice of delimiter: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yMmYD/

Comment: All I wanted was a quickie `alert` message to verify the arguments, eg: `title:title,text:<br>txt,type:success,delay:1500`.  Another quickie is `console.log arg`, and view it in the JavaScript console.

Comment: But why `join` an array that will only ever have one element? Why not use `(... for ...).join(', ')` so that you're building an array of strings rather than an array whose only element is an array of strings?

Comment: I think you're missing my point. If you `a = [x for x in ary]` then `a` will look like `[[...]]` but if you `a = (x for x in ary)` then you get an `a` that looks like `[...]`. You don't need the brackets to turn the loop into an array, it is an array already so the brackets give you an odd looking array-inside-an-array.

Comment: `["#{k}:#{v}" for k,v of arg]` has a string for each key in `arg`, in this case 4 strings. The `()` is fine too;  I've gotten into the `[]` habit with Python.

Comment: No, that is an array which contains an array of strings, try the jsfiddle.net link above and you'll see the difference. The parentheses and brackets produce difference results.

Comment: OK, I'm doing `[[1,2,3]].join()`, while thinking `[1,2,3].join(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

Without any fancy argument list manipulation, this is probably the best you can do while keeping it simple and understandable:

```
class Info extends Message
  log: (@title, @text, @delay, @class) ->
    super @title, @text, 1000, @class
```